# YouTrack Workflow - How to specify arguments to a custom command?

Tags: youtrack

I'm trying to make a custom command to clone an issue from one project to another one. To do this I would like the user to specify the new project as an argument to the command:

```
clone_to ProjectB
```

However there doesn't appear to be any way to get the argument string "ProjectB" in the actionFunction, like in the ctx argument:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/v1-entities.html#actionFunction

And there doesn't seem to be a way to define a command with an argument:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/rule-specific-properties.html#action-rule-properties
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/v1-Issue.html#action

Any ideas?

Comment: Ah shoot, looks like it's not possible right now: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-41751

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled upon [this fresh feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/cloud/action-rules.html#action-rules-with-user-input) resolving an [issue started 6 years ago](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-41751):
They literally use your clone_to request for demo)
I've tested this feature and it works fine.